# Log users activity on a PHP MySQL platform

Tags: php, mysql, logging, client

I've developed a server-client application based on the following idea:

A **Client** (windows application) work with a **Server** (PHP webpages) mostly like a client-server application based on sockets. Client send raw data to a PHP webpage, PHP script will check/process received data and finally script return an answer to client (data accepted/rejected/etc.).

The basic idea is that the **client** "ping" the **server** every X seconds even there the **client** is active or not. What is the best solution to log **client** activity?
  For example:

```
Client1 started application at Time1       and it "ping" Server for lets say 30 minutes, after that interval the Server stop receiving "pings" from the client;
Client2 started application at Time1+10min and it "ping" Server for lets say 40 minutes, after that interval the Server stop receiving "pings" from the client;
Client1 started application at Time1+35    and it "ping" Server for lets say 60 minutes, after that interval the Server stop receiving "pings" from the client;

** Server stop receiving "pings" from client means there is no activity for at least 1 minute
```

I need a final report who can give me the following data:

```
Client   |  Start at   |    End at   | Active
=========+=============+=============+========
Client1  | Time1       | Time1+30min | 30min 
Client2  | Time1+10min | Time1+50min | 40min 
Client1  | Time1+35min | Time1+95min | 60min
```

I don't have any clue how to make my MySQL log tables and what information to store in them via PHP for future reports.

*Any questions/observations are welcome.*

**EDIT: I don't need any PHP code to log my entryes, I don't need MySQL CREATE TABLE or SELECT command from you. I just ask for a good way to store all records, and a good way to retrieve some information from them. Thanks for downvoting the post without reading it until the end.**

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  What's wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: Almost nothing so far, except googled a lot about this concept... I don't have a good start point to achieve my goal. As I said in the end of the question: I don't have any clue how to make my MySQL log tables and what information to store in them via PHP for future reports.

Comment: How about making the client "ping" a real post/get request and log that request?

Comment: The client "ping" is a real post request. What about to log 3600 "pings" every hour for any client? And how to break then 50.000 log entryes in that final report?

Comment: Is the session variable in use anywhere? Set a session variable, increase it with each post request, and set a check at the script catching the post request to log it to DB every 60 count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MoeTsao's suggestion is not bad, considering you didn't define the "X" in "X seconds".  If "X" was around 3600 or more, it wouldn't be too bad.  Maybe you got downvoted for being pissy to him instead of taking his idea and modifying based on your (now elaborated) value of "X"?  As in...

Create a log table like this:

```
 client_id
 start_time
 end_time
```

then, on every request, do an UPDATE:

```
 update log_table
 set end_time = NOW()
 where client_id = $client_id
 and start_time >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute)
```

Check how many rows were updated (see your coding manual for that).

If one row was updated, you're done.  If none were updated, it's either a new client or a client that is idle and you must then do an insert:

```
 insert into log_table (client_id, start_time, end_time)
 values ($client_id, now(), now())
```

(contrary to my pseudo-code, please use positional parameters in your queries).

Creating the report is trivial (all necessary columns are in the row you're storing), and is left as an exercise for the original poster.  :)

Comment: awsome idea... exactly what i was looking for. I love the UPDATE + mysql_affected_rows() + INSERT algorithm. Thanks a lot.